# Unix Shell Script to extract the number from the String

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How to extract the bold number from the string below using unix shell script?

```
17: H.0(-2073):File ID (40008)in xyz file not equal to the file ID(**40004**)in file header.
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '17: H.0(-2073):File ID (40008)in xyz file not equal to the file ID(40004)in file header.' | sed -e 's/.*(\([0-9]*\)).*/\1/'
```

The second part of this line runs [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) with command `s` (substitution). Part between first two slashes (`/`) is [regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) which matches the following:

Everything (`.*`) in greedy manner, i.e. until the last occurrence of any number of digits in brackets ( `([0-9]*)` ) and then everything again (`.*`) until the end of line. Expression between `\(` and `\)` (i.e. `40004` in this case) is memorized to be used in the second part of `s` command.

The part between the second `/` and third `/` is what we want to place instead of the line matched with regular expression. Here it is `\1`, meaning reference to the substring between 1st occurrence of `\(` and `\)` which is `40004` in our case.

So the part after `|` replaces the whole input string with string `40004` extracted from it. Regular expressions are powerful but often write-only technique, so I hope this explanation will bring a bit more clarity.

Comment: could you please explain me the code ""sed -e 's/.*(\([0-9]*\)).*/\1/' "" How is it able to cut only Bold number?

Comment: @KK Added some explanation.